# Error on cronjob java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: mysql, clojure

Hello this is the error i am receiving and cannot seem to spot what is wrong with my SQL statement. Figured a extra pair of eyes couldn't hurt

```
UPDATE sales SET state_name =?, sales_id =null, sales_timer =null where entity_id =?
```

here is the function that houses that statement

```
(defn release
      [m]
      (db/execute!
        (core/db)
        (str "UPDATE sales SET state_name =?, sales_id =null, sales_timer =null where entity_id =?")
        [(name (m :current-state))
         (m :entity-id)]))
```

and here is the error we receive the error from

```
(defn get-unfinished-sales
    []
      (db/query
        (score/db)
        (str "select * from sales where state_name = 'in-progress'")))


 (defn unlock-sales
       [usales]
       (doall (map (fn [sale]
                       (->
                         (score/put-batch
                           {:user     core/system-user
                            :messages [{:entity-id (sale :entity-id)
                                        :message-type "release"
                                        :message {}}]
                            }
                           :sales)
                         (core/log-result-if-failure))) usales)))


(defn
  run
  [& args]
  (->>
    (get-unfinished-sales)
    (filter (fn [row] (not (nil? (row :sales-timer)))))
    (filter (fn [row] (> (t/in-hours (t/interval (row :sales-timer) (t/now))) 1)))
    (unlock-sales)))
```

Comment: I know it's clojure.

Comment: So where does the Java exception come from?

Comment: The Java exception comes from our logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `db/execute!` should put the SQL string as the first item in the vector with the parameters:

```
(defn release
      [m]
      (db/execute!
        (core/db)
        ["UPDATE sales SET state_name =?, sales_id =null, sales_timer =null where entity_id =?"
         (name (m :current-state))
         (m :entity-id)]))
```